# How to connect to Linux from Windows through SSH key based authentication?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I'm trying to connect from Windows 7 to a Linux Server using key based authentication. To do that, I've created the pair public/private keys using PuTTY keygen tool, and copied the content of the public key to the server's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file. When I'm using the `ssh` command line from my Windows OS and type: `ssh user@server` it asks for the password which shouldn't happen, because it has to read the private key from my `.ssh` folder:

[image: click to see image]

When I use PuTTY and I specify the private key I receive this message as well:

[image: click to see image]

My keys pair on my Windows OS is on the folder of my user account, under `.ssh`:

[image: click to see image]

And in the Linux server, the public key is inside the `authorized_keys` file in the `~/.ssh` folder:

[image: click to see image]

And my public key is this:

[image: click to see image]

I don't know what's wrong with all this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Your editor is showing `[noeol]` while viewing your public key in the `authorized_keys` file - that might be a problem. Add the missing end-of-line character.

Is the `authorized_keys` file on the Linux server protected so that other users of the server can not modify it? If not, then `sshd` will just ignore it. More specifically, the `authorized_keys` file, the `.ssh` sub-directory and the user's home directory all need to be writable only by the user himself.

If these tips won't solve the problem, check the server's authentication log. In Linux, that'll usually be either `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log` depending on distribution. The `sshd` daemon will log there an error message if it failed to read the `authorized_key` file or is ignoring it for some reason - and the error message will include the reason.

Comment: `ssh -v` (or even `ssh -vv`) will tell you more about what happens when you log in.

Comment: But it won't tell you *why* `sshd` rejects a key. That information is in the server log only.

Comment: Thank you @telcoM, I modified the permissions of the /home/eoecm01 folder. Now I have a message that says that my private keys are too open from my windows OS folder (0644), when I review my private key using Cygwin64 it has the 700 permissions. This is using the ssh utility program. When using putty it works fine. 

Thank you for your help